# jQuery Updating Class on Parent Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following layout:

```
<ul id="header">
     <li id="item1" class="off">   <a>Abc</a>   </li>
     <li id="item2" class="off">   <a>Abc</a>   </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on a href as in the `<a>` I want the class in the `<li>` for that to be updated.

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
$(".header > li a").click(function(){

      $(".header li a.current").removeClass("off");
        $(this).addClass("on");

});
```

Any ideas?

**--EDIT:**
Ok i just realized I'm not looking at this correctly.

So when clicking on that link a new page loads. So using the click function is wrong because a new page loads so whatever changes to the class i have will be lost. What i therefore need is to use the `$(document).ready(function()` to say something like "I clicked on li with id from the previous page so now update that class"

So

Thanks!

Comment: When i click on the link itself nothing happens. Is '$(".header > li a").click(function(){' def. correct??

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to get the parent `li` and then add the class:

```
$(this).closest("li").addClass("on");
```

you also need to use id selector `$("#header")` not class selector  `$(".header")`:

```
$("#header > li a").click(function(){

      $("#header li a.current").removeClass("off");
        $(this).closest("li").addClass("on");

});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/u36eU/2/)

Comment: +1 Side note: In English, sentences start with a capital letter. :-)

Answer (score 0):

USe

```
$(".header > li a").click(function(){
      $(".on").removeClass("on");
      $(this).closest("li").addClass("on");


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LDC69/1/

```
$("#header > li a").click(function(){    
      $(this).parent().removeClass("off").addClass("on");          
});
```

Its events chaining.

Look li is ID not CLASS.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9WTWT/32/)**
 Your `selector is wrong` $(".header") . In your html code  `<ul id="header">` so you have to use `id` selector `$("#header")`

```
$("#header li a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("on").addClass("off"); // Remove all class on and added off class
    $(this).parent().removeClass("off").addClass("on"); // Select current parent element and remove off and added on class


});
```